# intellij mocha plugin doesn't always use mocha

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, mocha.js, run-configuration

Normally from the IntelliJ's 'projects' pane, I can right click on a test file and choose 'debug' or 'run' and the **Mocha Plugin** intercepts it and automatically creates run/debug configurations for the file. This causes IntelliJ to use the following command:  *(note presence of mocha)*

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=57425 /projects/my_project/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --timeout 3600000 --ui bdd --reporter "/Users/shared/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2016.1/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" /projects/my_project/tests/src/scripts/my-other-test.js
```

Other times (for nearly identical files in the same folder) it doesn't: *(note mocha is absent)*

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=57068 my-test.js
```

The only way I've been able to run the test file is to manually create a *Run Configuration* specific to that file.

What do I have to do to encourage the **Mocha Plugin** to automatically create a run/debug configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `mocha` package is installed locally in your project. Mocha plugin checks that and creates mocha-command instead of node-command.

Comment: mocha package is installed locally. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't :(

Comment: These issues are fixed in WebStorm 2017.1.